# How directly to embed JavaScript into the Google Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to control every request entered in the address bar of the Google Chrome browser and display my custom message if the request has a word from an array in my JavaScript. As an option, I can create, upload to the Chrome Web Store and install from there my custom extension with JavaScript like

```
var url = document.URL;
var arrayOfWords = ["word1","word2","word3"];
for (i = 0; i < arrayOfWords.length; i++) {
    var encodedRequest = encodeURIComponent(arrayOfWords[i]);
    if(url.indexOf(encodedRequest) != -1) {
        document.write('The request has the word '+arrayOfWords[i]);
    }
}
```

and bind it to the JSON manifest file of the extension

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "js": ["myjavascriptfile.js"]
}
```

But an extension is not right for me (I won't explain why).

So I'm interested in how can I directly embed my JavaScript into the Google Chrome browser installed on my computer?

Please describe all the process in details for I'm not an expert in .DLL, .BAT and so on.

Comment: What was changed in December that prevented you from continuing to do it that way?

Comment: See your Developer Dashboard: _"As of November 21st, 2016, all newly published packaged or hosted apps are restricted to Chrome OS, and are not available to users on Windows, Mac or Linux"_

Comment: Ah, so you were doing it as an app, rather than an extension?

Comment: Yes, I got it. But at any case, it's not right for me. Added update to the question